# CF-2016 mappings doesn't find file from the specified location

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016, cfadmin

I have migrated from ColdFusion 8 to Coldfusion 2016 and specified the path under CF Admin console. See picture. One of my file (login.cfm) is under /common directory outside webroot. 
[image: Mappings]

When I hit application url, first it finds index.cfm and then validate.cfm in which I am calling login.cfm using cfmodule. PLs check the lines of code here from validate.cfm.

```
<cftry>
    <cfmodule template="/common/security/login.cfm"
            login="#form.login#"
            password="#form.password#"
            returnvar="login_result">

    <cfcatch>
        <cf_error_logreg error="An error occurred checking for active PO in validate.cfm. Please report this error to #request.app.admin_email# immediately.">
        <cfabort>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

So it doesn't run the cfmodule and throws out of cftry block everytime when it finds some page from /common directory and shows the error message what is specified in cfcatch block. Which means it's not accessing the mappings which I have set in CF Admin console. Any idea?
I am using IIS as a web server.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. The mappings we did was right, but Application was failing to set the cookies. ColdFusion was unable to add the cookie we specified to the response. This is probably because we have used it to set one of the ColdFusion Session Cookies or Authentication cookie. I have fixed that.
To fix this, I logged in to Coldfusion Admin> Memory Variables and unchecked 'Disable updating Coldfusion internal cookies using Coldfusion tags/functions.' 
Save settings and restarted the website. It worked.